# How to compose iterators?

Tags: python, function, functional-programming, iterator, generator

I have a network of nodes passing structured data in between. For my subproblem, we have this branch - linear sequence of nodes:

```
nodes = [source, n1, n2, n3, n4]
```

First node is a generator, each other node gets values from input node and provides output value. Current implementation is plain get() from a pipe and put() to a pipe and there is separate thread per node (there is reason for that). I want to change it to a `yield`-ing iterator.

And I want to evaluate in a following way (if we consider node to be a callable):

```
for result in n4(n3(n2(n1(source()))):
    print result
```

I imagine the construction of evaluation context like this:

```
context = src
for node in nodes[1:]:
    context = pipe(context, node)

for result in context:
    print result
```

**Limitations:**

I still want to be able to use nodes separately - not nested, piping data by other means, because the nodes might be in separate threads. Example: `[source, n1,n2]` in one thread (might be nested), `[n3, n4]` in the other (might be nested), data piped between `n2` and `n3`. Case: there might be a non-linear node graph where I want to group branches this way.

`node` has to be a class to hold computation state

How the implementation of the `context` and the `pipe(context, node)` might look like? Or if it can be solved in a different way, do you have any hints?

Can `yield from` in Python 3.3 [(PEP380)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) help my case in any way?

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to compose arbitrary numbers of functions (or callables), use the [`compose_mult` recipe](http://oakwinter.com/code/functional/documentation/cookbook.html) from the `functional` module documentation.

A solution which uses that:

```
from functional import compose, foldr, partial
from itertools  import imap
compose_mult = partial(reduce, compose) 
chain_nodes = lambda nodes: imap(compose_mult(nodes[1:]), nodes[0])
chain_gen_nodes = lambda nodes: imap(compose_mult((g.send for g in nodes[1:])), nodes[0])


# equivalent not as a one-liner
#def chain_nodes(nodes):
#    source = nodes[0]
#    composed_nodes = compose_mult(nodes[1:])
#    return (composed_nodes(x) for x in source)
```

If the nodes are generators that accept input (via `send`), then use `chain_gen_nodes`, which extracts their send function.

Note, however, that one is not allowed to `send` to a just-started generator (because it has to be at the point of a `yield` to receive the value). This is something you are going to have to handle yourself, such as by having your generators `yield` a dummy value on their first iteration, and advancing them at some point before sending them to `chain_nodes`. Or you could just keep your nodes as ordinary callables.

If you do need to advance the iterators one step: `next(izip(*nodes[1:]))`

Comment: That is what I wrote in my question - that is the principle I want to achieve. Problem is, that the list of nodes is not known prior to computation. That is why I have listed nodes as an array `nodes = [...]`.

Comment: @Stiivi It is not what you wrote. However, I have updated my answer.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear enough and thank you for your suggestion - seems to be useful solution. Do you think it can be done using standard python library ('no' or 'too complicated' is also accepted simple answer)? I would like to avoid more dependencies (`functional` in this case).

Comment: @Stiivi `reduce` and `partial` exist in the standard library. You can probably roll your own version of `compose` quite easily.